# How many anonymous functions can I call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just in the process of studying jquery. And I have the following question. I have a page that relies on js for ajax and reporting to user.

So basically I have created a file with `$(function() {})` construct. Inside of that construct I'm using standard jquery functionality to work with my modal windows, smth. like

```
 $('.text-danger').hide();
    $(".btnajax").click(function() {})
```

But now I want to work with another modal window at the same page, not at the same time. What would be a better way:

1. Continue inside the same anonymous function construct and keep working with IDs and Classes when referencing the specific buttons and form actions?
   OR
2. Create new anonymous function construct? OR
3. Create named functions and call them when needed?

I would like to build correctly from the scratch, so I don't have to redo everything later when I'm better with JS.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you mean 2 popup will open at same time ?

Comment: popup or modal?

Comment: Two popups not at the same time. But on the same page.

Comment: And sorry for terminology. Modals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Continue inside the same anonymous function construct and keep working
>   with IDs and Classes when referencing the specific buttons and form
>   actions?

This is not a good idea as every time you would do something with the buttons or the form it would access the DOM which is unnecessarily expensive.

> Create new anonymous function construct?

Actually, anonymous functions are rarely a good idea as they make your code hard to read. Imagine there are no named functions and everything is anonymous. That would require the reader to always get the context in order to quickly understand what the function is doing

> Create named functions and call them when needed?

Especially when reusing that functionality, it's a good idea. But also in terms of readability it is good because the name of the function describes what is happening so when someone (you) read the code again after some time, will know hat is happening without studying the body of the functions.

Apart from that:

> I would like to build correctly from the scratch, so I don't have to redo everything later when I'm better with JS.

I can tell you: you will not avoid rewriting parts of your code once the requirements change. That is just what coding is about. You can not foresee every required change to your application. If you try to then you end up having an over engineered code. Instead, you should follow [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).
Generally speaking, for everything that's more than just 5 buttons and a form, a JS file with jQuery is not the way to go. Those times are over. Switch to something that gives you a separation of concerns between model, (model)view and controller.